# Rewriting subdomains to subfolders and parameter in IIS

Tags: iis

I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem;

I have a default site with an application that resides in a subfolder, e.g. /app/app.html

It also accepts a language parameter, so for example http://192.168.0.1/app/app.html?language=fi would work.

Now I have two subdomains that I need to not only get rewritten to the correct folder, but also include the language parameter. For example:

fi.domain.com -> http://1.1.1.1/app/app.html?language=fi

swe.domain.com -> http://1.1.1.1/app/app.html?language=swe

I've made A records for both subdomains to point to 1.1.1.1

Currently there are no special bindings (only port 80, no hostnames and all IPs) and no special default pages.

EDIT: I've tried using the URL rewriter module, but I haven't been able to get it work as intended.

EDIT 2: My first example of how I need it to work was a bit flawed, here's a better version;

finnishword.domain.com -> http://1.1.1.1/app/app.html?language=fi

otherwordinswedish.domain.com -> http://1.1.1.1/app/app.html?language=swe

Comment: Have you tried the `UrlRewrite` module and/or the rewrite rules in the ARR? You haven't described your current approach which could possibly mean you miss these two obvious possiblities.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, see my edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to well understand your question.
It seems that you need URL rewriting rules.

According to this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-city-domain-com-to-domain-com-city)

```
<rule name="CName to URL - Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/app.html?language={C:1}" />
</rule>
```

I think it's what you need ;)

**Edit 24/08/2016**
If you can't have a dynmique pattern with RegEx you have to do as many rules as you have subdomains:

```
<rule name="finnishRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(finnishword)\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/app.html?language=fi" />
</rule>
<rule name="finnishRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(otherwordinswedish)\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/app.html?language=swe" />
</rule>
```

or you can mixup all together if you want to redirect all subdomains that contains the word "swedish" on url with ?

```
<rule name="finnishRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*swedish.*)\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/app.html?language=swe" />
</rule>
```

So after all the RegEx pattern is up to you ;)

**Edit 25/08/2016**

Maybe you have to add condition to skip static files

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
...
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'll try that and report back, I don't have that much experience with the rewriting rules so I must have done it somehow backwards!

Comment: Hmm, I see now how that is supposed to work, but I also noticed that my example was a bit flawed. The subdomain doesn't match the language parameter as in my example, see my second edit for a more accurate example.

Comment: Simply change the pattern will do the trick, so you have to do multiple rules, one for each subdomain. I wil edit the answer soon

Comment: Perfect, I imagined that pattern matching was the way to go, and I only have two subdomains so it won't get too insane. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to see it works for you. You may put the answered flag to it ;)

Comment: Meh, still can't get this to work properly :)

It rewrites the URL fine, but it breaks the site instead. It seems to request other stuff located in subfolders (/app/content/something.css) and these requests doesn't seem to go through. More rewrite rules? :)

Comment: Related to the <match url=".*" />, like this it may handle more than aspx page

Comment: I edited the answer I think this is the way to go but I haven't the time to test it for now ^^'

Comment: You where on the right track, I'll add how I did it in a separate answer! Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="swedishMainRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?swedishword\.domain\.fi$" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="language=" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="?language=sve" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="swedishRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?swedishword\.domain\.fi$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="finnishRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?anotherfinnishword\.domain\.fi$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

This is how I ended up doing it, basically the first rule deal with the language parameter, and the other rules just rewrite the URL. The Finnish rule doesn't need an extra language rule since the default language of the app is Finnish.